# Removed and Reinserted second drive, BitLocker will not unlock automatically, asking for key

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bitlocker

Laptop has 2x NVME slots.  Primary is 480GB Intel SSD.  Secondary was empty.  Added 1 TB Samsung EVO 960 (I think).  Needed room for VMs.  Was looking to upgrade my primary SSD to a 2 TB Samsung EVO 980 PRO.  Removed secondary, put in the new 980.  Cloning failed because of BitLocker.  Oh well, swapped back in the old D: drive (EVO 960 1TB).  Windows now says it's locked and that I need the recovery key to unlock it.  It came from this machine, this Windows installation, and is going back into the same machine after only a few hours.

Is there any way to see if Windows can just use cached information to use the drive again?

Comment: Cloning failed because of pre-existing BitLocker managed by the company.    ..... Company issue - call them

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Needs  to be referred to company. Corporate question

Comment: The cloning failing isn't the issue.  Bitlocker failing to unlock a drive that was already attached at one point is the issue.

Comment: Did you a) disable Secure Boot or b) enable CSM/BIOS boot during the cloning process?

Comment: Changed nothing during the cloning process.  I can check its current status, but none of that was changed.  Swapped SSD#2, booted, clone attempt, shut down, Swapped SSD#2 to original hardware, booted and that's its current state.